# What is the "correct" way of making $\mathcal{P}(X)$ into a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, definition

If $X$ is a topological space, I want to know the "correct" way of making the powerset $\mathcal{P}(X)$ into a topological space. So let $\mathsf{SupLat}$ denote the infinitary Lawvere theory whose models in $\mathbf{Set}$ are precisely the [suplattices](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/suplattice). Write $\mathbf{TopSupLat}$ for the category of models of $\mathsf{SupLat}$ in $\mathbf{Top}.$ There is a forgetful functor $$U : \mathbf{TopSupLat} \rightarrow \mathbf{Top}.$$

Does it have a left-adjoint $F$? If so, I'd like to see an explicit description of $F(X)$ for an arbitrary topological space $X$.

Comment: Question:; $\mathcal P(X)$ is the power-set of $X$?

Comment: @GEdgar, yes sir.

Comment: I think your question/construction has to do with [Alexandrov topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology).

Comment: I would suggest to think of $P(X)$ as $\hom(X,\{0,1\})$ and use function space topologies.